# Получения доступа к хэшу

Tags: ruby

```
inventory = {
     soccer_ball: {qty: 2},
     tennis_ball: {qty: 3}
}

puts inventory[soccer_ball]
```

Не работает доступ по хэшу, в чём причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда задаёте вопрос, указывайте пожалуйста более развёрнуто, что значит "не работает". В данном случае, я полагаю, вы получаете

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `soccer_ball'
```

Причина в том, что ключами в вашем хэше являются символы (`:soccer_ball`, например). Вы просто забыли двоеточие при обращении, и `soccer_ball` было расценено, как название переменной/метода. Вот так всё будет работать:

```
puts inventory[:soccer_ball]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое